# How to display DFP Ad using Angular 7?

Tags: angular

I am developing an app using PWA. I am using Angular 7 to meet our requirement. Basically, it is a media application which plays videos. Now our requirement is to show DFP Ad in it. I have searched and try to implement DFP Ad but did not get success.
Please suggest and give any reference URL to implement.